# Modal fixed position content shift

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

After a lot of research, I am [unable to find a proper solution](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040) for the **shifting to the right of fixed positioned elements**, cover images, and standard content, when a modal window is open.

**Note**: I am looking for a general, clean solution, not an hardcoded fix that would work just on a specific layout.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Please refer to this example: http://codepen.io/microcipcip/pen/kXdRWK

```
body {
  height: 2500px;
  &.-modal-open {
      overflow: hidden;
  }
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #FF0000;
}
.modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    body.-modal-open & {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because of `&.-modal-open {overflow: hidden;}`. Check by commenting it!

Comment: That would give me two scrollbars. I can't remove the `overflow: hidden;` from the body because it would also allow scrolling on mobile devices (basically you wouldn't be able to scroll the modal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is very simple and a pure css fix:

```
.-modal-open .fixed,
.-modal-open .content {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

..however, this requires that your content is styled differently. You should never use a margin for your content, but rather wrap it in a container and use padding instead.

The scrollbar's width isn't always 17px... 17px is for Firefox, but 15px for chrome, sometimes IE doesn't even have a scrollbar width depending on the code.

Here is the updated pen:
http://codepen.io/scooterlord/pen/KgKLwB

edit: forgot to say, that this is a cross-browser solution and works flawlessly everywhere I tested it. If the browser is mobile, then no change of width happens anyway from the addition/removal of the extra scrollbars and depending on the browser the newly created scrollbars for the content/fixed elements is always the same as the initial body scrollbar.

Comment: This is a really clever solution! Basically you're compensating the removal of the scroll in the body with the addition of the scroll in the content container.

Comment: Yep that's about it

Comment: Any possible solution for the shift of the cover background? I tried to move it inside the container but it is still shifting

Comment: You have background-size:cover on the background. Probably this is not the actual background you want to use to your final project, so depending on the actual background there might be a way to do it - but have to see it first.

Comment: I don't think it is important what background is being used, usually I set it to `background-size: cover;`, and that shifts when the modal is open. I tried to move the background to the container but that doesn't fix it. Obviously I'd rather use the `background-attachment: fixed;`, but I still see the issue: http://codepen.io/microcipcip/pen/pEvZrV

Comment: This is irrelevant, but attachment:fixed causes serious performance issues on mobile devices, so normally you should avoid it. The cover background-size is container width dependent, so when a scrollbar disappears, the background resizes; the only thing I could think of as a solution (not mobile friendly though) is to use an overflown fixed container on top of the body for your content and set the body to overflow:hidden and attach all modal-open classes to the overflown container. Other than that, I would suggest you used one of the many plugins that add a custom scrollbar like tiny-scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

The main trick is to not use body as your content wrapper. Use a dedicated div as wrapper and place your modals outside so the scrollbars don't interfere with each other.

```js
var $btnShow = document.querySelector('.show');
var $btnHide = document.querySelector('.hide');
var $body = document.querySelector('.modal');
$btnShow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $body.classList.toggle('-modal-open')
});
$btnHide.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $body.classList.toggle('-modal-open')
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  background: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/m16kxhb2jg5jwwh/bear-800x450.jpg?dl=0&raw=1');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 2500px;
  width: 100%; 
}

.clickme {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.clickme:hover {
  background: grey;
  cursor:pointer
}

.modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 3;
}
.modal.-modal-open {
  display:block;
}
.modal-content {
  min-height: 1500px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/u520y7yo711uaxi/poster2.jpg?dl=0&raw=1');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">Content
    <button class="clickme hide">Toggle Modal HIDE!</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
<button class="clickme show">Toggle Modal SHOW!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for, but the whole content area now is a fixed positioned element, I'll have a look and see if this solution can be used on the normal flow of the page

Comment: jea it can just make sure it is the first div and treat it like its the body tag

Answer (score -1):

How about adding 17px right-margin to the body each time a modal is opened. That would emulate the space that was reserved for the scroll bar. (17px is the width of standard browser width)

```
body.-modal-open {
    margin-right: 17px;
}
```

meanwhile, for for fixed element you recalculate the width;

```
.-modal-open .fixed {
    width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
```

There is still one problem though, the CSS background image is still shifted, the solution is simply placing it in a div container instead of the body.

Comment: The width of the scrollbar is Browser **AND** OS dependent. Chrome/Linux is 15px whereas the same on Windows is 17px. For Firefox its 13px on Linux. I'm guessing all of that is a different number on Mac.